# Cyclic loading on ABAQUS CAE

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, finite-element-method, abaqus

I am new to abaqus and for my final year project I'm meant to simulate a force on a cylinder (testing displacement of articular cartilage) ranging from 1-15 Hz and between 15-36 Newtons but I don't know how to do it. I have all the necessary material parameters I just don't know how to apply the loading. Any help, guides or tutorials would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: look up Amplitude in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

In general, how you use ABAQUS depends on what you are looking to observe. Are you hoping to simply observe stress or deflection as a function of time? Are you trying to simulate damage or failure? These considerations matter at a basic level.

On a simple level, there are several steps in creating an ABAQUS file from CAE.
1. Creating the geometry of a part.
2. Creating a material.
3. Assigning a section to your part, thereby specifying the material.
4. Meshing the part.
5. Assigning loading, boundary, constraints, and interactions depending on the scenario.

You should easily be able to accomplish all of these things with any amount of googling. There are many tutorials out there. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7keHd1KeGjQ) is a tutorial showing a cyclic loading on a cylinder, for example. You should be able to follow steps of these tutorials.